# How to “save” my JS Change in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need when the visitor chooses one, This change is saved in the localStorage, but I do not know how to do it. I've tried a lot by looking at examples on the internet but none fit my case and I got lost. here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // better body background color changing function
    $('.menu-thing').click(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('whoa4'); 
        $('.face4.two4').removeClass('visible17');
        $('#wrap').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color')); 
        return false;
    });

    $('.whoa-button4').click(function(){
        $('body').toggleClass('whoa4'); 
        $('.face4.two4').toggleClass('visible17');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "saving style"?

Comment: Text successfully edited

Comment: name your event handler functions, and make them non-anon. save a flag to localstorage from inside the function. onload, check localStorage for the flag, and if present, call the function that set the flag to re-apply the same thing the user did.

Comment: Do not know how to handle it?

Comment: @hamesashek It's not an issue about not knowing how to handle it. Your intent is not entirely clear. What exactly do you want saved when the user clicks?

Comment: The page color is not saved after you refresh your browser jsfiddle.net/hamesashek/hf8yLcrk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../libraries/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menuStyles.css">
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="menuCheckbox"/>
<div class="menu-container">
    <label class="menu-label" for="menuCheckbox">
        <div class="white-line"></div>
    </label>
    <div class="menu-thing side one">:D</div>
    <div class="menu-thing side two">( ._.)</div>
    <div class="menu-thing side three">n_n</div>
    <div class="menu-thing side four">:)</div>
</div>
<div class="face"></div>
<div class="face two"></div>
<div class="whoa-button">:O</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I reworked this locally to ensure it is working. This is the javascript.

```
$(function(){

$('body').css('background-color', loadBG); 

$('.menu-thing').click(function(){
$('body').removeClass('whoa'); 
$('.face.two').removeClass('visible');
$('body').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color')); 
setStorage('bgColor', $(this).css('background-color'));
return false;
});

$('.whoa-button').click(function(){
$('body').toggleClass('whoa'); 
$('.face.two').toggleClass('visible');
return false;
});

function loadBG(){
    var bgColor = getStorage('bgColor');
    if (bgColor != "none"){
        return bgColor;
    } else {
        var currentColor = $('body').css('background-color');
        return currentColor;
    }
}

function setStorage(key,info) {
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(info));
}

function getStorage(key) {
var item = localStorage.getItem(key);
if(item != "undefined" && item != null){
    return JSON.parse(item);
} else {
    return "none";
}
}
});
```

I did verify it saves the bg color in local storage after each click.It uses the css you provided in the fiddle. of **note(!)** I did reference jquery because you were using jquery syntax and you'll have to rename the .css file to what you desire.

Comment: Do not know how to handle it?
Can you help me make these changes in the educational program?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to save in local storage? When the use clicks, what should be saved?

Comment: The page color is not saved after you refresh your browser https://jsfiddle.net/hamesashek/hf8yLcrk/

Comment: @hamesashek I updated my answer, I verified it is saving bg color in local storage. From here I think you can get the values you need/edit and correct this code as you see fit.

Comment: Have you placed the code as it is and the color has not been saved?

Comment: Not working just fine
There seems to be a reason to make it not work

Comment: If you want to post your html, css, and javascript I'll try it locally. The fiddle isn't a great place for this since the functionality you want requires a refresh to occur.

Comment: I did it before, the local experience was done and I could not see the correct results to be saved the color of the page after the update
I apologize for your effort

Comment: No need to apologize, I hope you were able to solve your problem. If not, feel free to post the html, css, and javascript and I will try to solve it on my machine and share the answer with you.

Comment: Thank you my dear friend
This is a preview link for work       https://jsfiddle.net/hamesashek/hf8yLcrk/2/

Comment: @hamesashek check it out now. It should be working. If it does please accept my answer. :)